# 502 Bad Gateway with nginx and php7.0-fpm on docker

Tags: nginx, php-7

I have created docker image, which includes the Debian packages `nginx-full, php7.0, php7.0-fpm, php-zmq` and application code written in PHP.

When I am trying to invoke the application from a browser (basically calling `zeroMQ`), I receive a 502 bad gateway error. How can I find out whether it is a server or a code problem?

Tried changing the permission to the socket file and
not able to print the PATH_INFO variable.

**Nginx log**:

```
157#157: *622 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
```

**PHP-FPM log**:

```
[02-Apr-2018 16:05:26] WARNING: [pool www] child 197 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 79.435089 seconds from start
[02-Apr-2018 16:05:26] NOTICE: [pool www] child 203 started
```

**nginx configuration:**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                }
```

**PHP-FPM configuration** :

```
user = www-data
group = www-data

//tried  127.0.0.1:900 but did not work
listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

After receiving the error, when I do `php-fpm` reload, the error goes off. But then will happen again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I updated the formatting of your question to improve the readability and included tag php-7. This helps users with knowledge of the subject to spot issues more easily.

You already formatted the titles to show bold. For the markup to render correctly, the spacing of intends and extra lines is important. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more information on formatting.

Please verify that the content of your question looks correct now. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug, try using this update: 
[Dockerfile](https://github.com/dmstr/docker-php-yii2/commit/58a9b1bb88637c28ceb1ba6fce39c48aa876021b)

Comment: I have already tried that, as in by project /var/run has a link to /run path. I thought it would be same.

Comment: Edited my answer